# Cannot GET aurelia packages using material design lite

Tags: typescript, aurelia, material-design-lite

Trying to build with Aurelia using Typescript and adding material design lite. I'm simply cloning the navigation-skeleton but with typescript.

However, I receive multiple errors in f12:

[Lines in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPj71.png)

Which expand out to something such as:

```
Cannot GET /jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.0.1/
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-skeleton-navigation",
  "version": "0.19.0",
  "description": "A starter kit for building a standard navigation-style app with Aurelia.",
  "keywords": [
    "aurelia",
    "navigation",
    "skeleton"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://aurelia.io",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues"
  },
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "author": "Rob Eisenberg <rob@bluespire.com> (http://robeisenberg.com/)",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test",
    "e2e": "gulp serve e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aurelia-bundler": "^0.1.8",
    "aurelia-tools": "^0.1.3",
    "babel": "^5.8.23",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
    "browser-sync": "^1.8.1",
    "conventional-changelog": "0.0.11",
    "del": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-bump": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^0.6.6",
    "gulp-protractor": "^0.0.12",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "gulp-yuidoc": "^0.1.2",
    "isparta": "^3.1.0",
    "istanbul": "gotwarlost/istanbul#source-map",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.1.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "jspm": "^0.16.11",
    "karma": "^0.12.37",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^5.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-coverage": "douglasduteil/karma-coverage#next",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-jspm": "2.0.1-beta.2",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "0.0.21",
    "object.assign": "^1.0.3",
    "require-dir": "^0.1.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "tsd": "^0.6.5",
    "vinyl-paths": "^1.0.0",
    "yargs": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1",
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1",
      "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@^1.0.0-beta.1",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.2",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.2",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.4",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.2.6",
      "fetch": "github:github/fetch@^0.9.0",
      "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@^4.3.0",
      "material-design-lite": "github:google/material-design-lite@^1.0.6",
      "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.2.6"
    },
    "overrides": {
      "github:google/material-design-lite@1.0.6": {
        "main": "material"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you forgot to `npm install` and `jspm install` after cloning the repository.  Simply do those two (which are listed in the README.md) and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

From mdl documentation:

> Material Design Lite will automatically register and render all elements marked with MDL classes upon page load. However in the case where you are creating DOM elements dynamically you need to register new elements using the `upgradeElement` function.

Aurelia dynamically loads the views. That being said, you need to call `upgradeElement` for each element with mdl- css class.

Try this plugin: https://github.com/genadis/aurelia-mdl